# RecordTypeId and API INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: rest-api, record-type

Currently I am just trying to insert a new Customer, which is just a custom name for an account using the rest API. I am getting the following error related to RecordTypeId which I am confused about since I am pulling the right ID.

```
{
    "message": "Customer Record Type: this ID value isn't valid for the user: 0124W000001LQCqQAO",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY",
    "fields": [
        "RecordTypeId"
    ]
}
```

Here are 2 images showing how I obtained this RecordTypeId.

[image]

[image]

As you can see above the record type attached to my Customer object is "AccountRecord Type I Made".
In the second picture I am showing the URL which is where I got the RecordTypeId that I am passing. Here is the JSON I am sending to the API.

```
{
"RecordTypeId": "0124W000001LQCqQAO",
"Customer_ID__c": "999999",
"Name": "Test User",
"PersonEmail": "testemail@gmail.com",
"Phone": "469-999-8888",
"Sign_Up_date__c": "2021-01-25",
"BillingStreet": "1111 Maple Ave",
"BillingCity": "Dallas",
"BillingState": "Texas",
"BillingPostalCode": "75235",
"BillingCountry": "USA"
}
```

Appreciate any help, I am pulling my hair out over this one, been stuck on it since last week.

Comment: Did you check that user has the record type available on profile level?

Comment: I am having a hard time finding that, I didn't setup the Salesforce instance or even know how, I was just tasked with the API so I am learning as I go. Is that in Setup>Users>Profile? What do I need to be looking for? I clicked System Administrator which but cannot find record type permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users in the org need to be explicitly granted access to record types on objects. This can be done by profiles or permission sets.

Access to the available record types is found under:

```
Setup > Users > Profiles > [select one] > Object Settings > top section
```

The screenshot below shows a system administrator profile with access to just some of the available record types on the Account object.

[image]